# API Connect Developer Portal giving error as (IP) has been banned

Tags: api, websphere, apiconnect

Today All of a sudden developer portal of one of the catalog in IBM API Connect started throwing the error as (IP) has been banned. Any idea guys how to fix this ? I did restart of portal services but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Drupal feature.  Login as admin to your portal, then navigate to Configuration > People.  Everything you need is under there.  You can remove the ban, set the limits and clear all tables.